# ApiPaltform - recover soft deleted element

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com, soft-delete, doctrine-extensions

I'm using `ApiPlatform` and `Symfony5`

I've implemented `softdelete` on an entity `User`

This entity is softdeleted properly, I still want to displayed the deleted users for some roles, so I'm trying a `DoctrineExtension` to modify the request dynamically.

Here is my `UserExtension.php`:

```
    public function applyToItem(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
    {

        if (User::class == $resourceClass &&
            $this->security->isGranted(GenericRoles::ROLE_ADMIN)
        ) {
            $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

            $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.deletedAt > '2019-01-01'");
        }
    }
```

I verified that I enter in the if condition.

But I still get a `404` on the item I'm trying to recover (which is still in base)

The same request entered in command line in the db return me the item I want to recover.

I've also tried to disable `softdelete` as follow :

`$this->entityManager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');`

But doing so disable it for the whole application, and I can't re enable it in the `UserExtension`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ? Or if there is another way to recover soft deleted items

Or if you got more docs on the subject I'd be gratefull cause I'm runnning out of options

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me, I hope it'll work for whoever fall onto this :

Through a `DataProvider` it's possbile to `disable` the filter, query the soft deleted object you want to query and stock it in a variable, then `enable` the filter again and return your object.

I don't know if using the a `DataProvider` this way is a good practice, but it has not created side effect on my application.

Here is an example:

```
    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted(GenericRoles::ROLE_ADMIN))
        ) {
            $this->entityManager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }

        $softDeletedObject = $this->itemDataProvider->getItem($resourceClass, $id, $operationName, $context);

        $this->entityManager->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');

        return $softDeletedObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's not straightforward, as your query executes outside of the extension. I would probably try to disable soft deletable filter for User entity only in case authenticated user has Admin role. It still would be disabled after the execution of the query, but it shouldn't cause too many side effects, as admin user should be able to see deleted User entities. Something like this.

```
public function applyToItem(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): void
{
    $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
}

private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
{
    if (User::class === $resourceClass &&
        $this->security->isGranted(GenericRoles::ROLE_ADMIN)
    ) {
        $filter = $this->entityManager->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
        $filter->disableForEntity(User::class);

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.deletedAt > '2019-01-01'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I havn't tried this solution, but through a `DataProvider` I can `disable` the filter, query the entity I want to query and then `enable` the filter again, while returning the object of interest.